# What is the output of the following code in C?

Tags: c, string, pointers, character

Please take a look at this code.

```
 #include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *p;
    p = "%d";
    p++;
    p++;
    printf(p-2,23);
    return 0;
}
```

I have the following questions

1) How can a pointer to a character data type can hold a string data type?
2) What happens when p is incremented twice?
3) How can the `printf()`can print a string when no apparent quotation marks are used?

Comment: The pointer doesn't hold the data.  It holds the address of the data.

Comment: You need to learn what a C "string" is. Ak your teacher or - better - read in your C textbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"How can a pointer to a character data type can hold a string data type?"  Well, it's partly true that in C, type 'pointer to char' *is* the string type.  Any function that operates on strings (including `printf`) will be found to accept these strings via parameters of type `char *`.

"How can `printf()` print a string when no apparent quotation marks are used?"  There's no rule that says you need quotation marks to have a string!  That thing with quotation marks is a *string constant* or *string literal*, and it's one way to get a string into your program, but it's not at all the only way.  There are lots of ways to construct (and manipulate, and modify) strings that don't involve any quotation marks at all.

Let's draw some pictures representing your code:

```
char *p;
```

`p` is a pointer to `char`, but as you correctly note, it doesn't point anywhere yet.  We can represent it graphically like this:

```
   +-----------+
p: |    ???    |
   +-----------+
```

Next you set `p` to point somewhere:

```
p = "%d";
```

This allocates the string `"%d"` somewhere (it doesn't matter where), and sets `p` to point to it:

```
   +---+---+---+
   | % | d |\0 |
   +---+---+---+
     ^
     |
      \
       \
        \
         |
   +-----|-----+
p: |     *     |
   +-----------+
```

Next, you start incrementing `p`:

```
p++;
```

As you said, this makes `p` point one past where it used to, to the second character of the string:

```
   +---+---+---+
   | % | d |\0 |
   +---+---+---+
         ^
         |
         |
         |
         |
         |
   +-----|-----+
p: |     *     |
   +-----------+
```

Next,

```
p++;
```

Now we have:

```
   +---+---+---+
   | % | d |\0 |
   +---+---+---+
             ^
             |
            /
           /
          /
         |
   +-----|-----+
p: |     *     |
   +-----------+
```

Next you called `printf`, but somewhat strangely:

```
printf(p-2,23);
```

The key to that is the expression `p-2`.  If `p` points to the third character in the string, then `p-2` points to the first character in the string:

```
         +---+---+---+
         | % | d |\0 |
         +---+---+---+
           ^       ^
      +----|----+  |
 p-2: |    *    | /
      +---------+/
                /
               |
         +-----|-----+
      p: |     *     |
         +-----------+
```

And that pointer, `p-2`, is more or less the same pointer that `printf` would have received if you're more conventionally called `printf("%d", 23)`.

Now, if you thought `printf` received a string, it may surprise you to hear that `printf` is happy to receive a `char *` instead — and that in fact it *always* receives a `char *`.  If this is surprising, ask yourself, what did you thing `printf` *did* receive, if not a pointer to `char`?

Strictly speaking, a string in C is an array of characters (terminated with the `'\0'` character).  But there's this super-important secret fact about C, which if you haven't encountered yet you will real soon (because it's really not a secret at all):

> You can't do much with arrays in C.  Whenever you mention an array in an expression in C, whenever it looks like you're trying to do something with the value of the array, what you get is a pointer to the array's first element.

That pointer is pretty much the "value" of the array.  Due to the way pointer arithmetic works, you can use pointers to access arrays pretty much transparently (almost as if the pointer *was* the array, but of course it's not).  And this all applies perfectly well to arrays of (and pointers to) characters, as well.

So since a string in C is an array of characters, when you write

```
"%d"
```

that's an array of three characters.  But when you use it in an expression, what you get is a pointer to the array's first element.  For example, if you write

```
printf("%d", 23);
```

you've got an array of characters, and you're mentioning it in an expression, so what you get is a pointer to the array's first element, and that's what gets passed to `printf`.

If we said

```
char *p = "%d";
printf(p, 23);
```

we've done the same thing, just a bit more explicitly: again, we've mentioned the array `"%d"` in an expression, so what we get as its value is a pointer to its first element, so that's the pointer that's used to initialize the pointer variable `p`, and that's the pointer that gets passed as the first argument to `printf`, so `printf` is happy.

Up above, I said "it's partly true that in C, type 'pointer to char' is the string type".  Later I said that "a string in C is an array of characters".  So which is it?  An array or a pointer?  Strictly speaking, a string is an array of characters.  But like all arrays, we can't do much with an array of characters, and when we try, what we get is a pointer to the first element.  So most of the time, strings in C are accessed and manipulated and modified via pointers to characters.  All functions that operate on strings (including `printf`) actually receive pointers to char, pointing at the strings they'll manipulate.

Comment: Thanks @Steve Summit for this clear explanation. Despite the downvotes to this question, I have learned something new.

Answer (score 0):

the following explains each statement in the posted code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>// include the header file that has the prototype for 'printf()'

int main( void )   // correct signature of 'main' function
{
    char *p;       // declare a pointer to char, do not initialize
    p = "%d";      // assign address of string to pointer
    p++;           // increment pointer (so points to second char in string
    p++;           // increment pointer (so points to third char in string
    printf(p-2,23);// use string as 'format string' in print statement, 
                   // and pass a parameter of 23
    return 0;      // exit the program, returning 0 to the OS
}
```

Comment: Thanks @user3629249 for explaining this code line by line.

Answer (score 0):

1) How can a pointer to a character data type can hold a string data type?

Ans: String is not a basic data type in C. String is nothing but a continuous placement of char in memory until '\0' is encountered.

2) What happens when p is incremented twice?

Ans: It now points to the '\0' character.

3) How can the printf()can print a string when no apparent quotation marks are used

Ans: A string is always represented in quotation marks so extra quotes are not needed.

Comment: Thanks @Sandeep for your answers!

Answer (score -1):

**1. How can a pointer to a character data type can hold a string data type?**

*-> `Char pointer` will hold the address of `char datatype`, since `string` is collection of `char datatypes`. Hence `char` `pointer` can hold the `string` data type..*

**2. What happens when `p` is incremented twice?**

*-> When you assign the `char` `pointer` to `string` pointer will point to first char. So when you increment the pointer twice, it will hold the address of 3rd char, in your case it is'\0';*

**3. How can the printf()can print a string when no apparent quotation marks are used**?

*->    `printf(p-2,23);` Uses string as format identifier in your case it is `"%d"`.*

Comment: Thanks @kiran Birandar for posting your valuable answer.